# How to json_decode an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array of objects.

```
$arr = array(0 => o1, 1 => o2);
```

I get proper json_encode for this. Say, I have:

```
$json_data = json_encode($arr);
```

BUT, when I `json_decode` the `$json_data` variable, 
with 2nd argument true I get everything in array format:

```
array(0 => array, 1 =>array)
```

with 2nd argument false I get everything in object format:

```
object(0 => object, 1 => object)
```

How to get the original array back? I.e. how to get

```
array(0 => object, 1 => object)
```

Edit: paraphrasing my question. When we json_encode an array of objects, how to get back the same array of objects when you json_decode the encoded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following code on PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 (cli), and surprisingly got exactly what I wanted. Since this question is so old, I don't remember what was the PHP version when I tried this at the time of posting this code.

Code:

```
<?php
class Test {
        public $message = "this is message";
        public $number = 10;
}
$t1 = new Test();
$t2 = new Test();
$arr = array(0 => $t1, 1 => $t2);
$json_data = json_encode($arr);
var_dump($json_data);
$original_array = json_decode($json_data, true);
$original_object = json_decode($json_data, false);
var_dump($original_array);
var_dump($original_object);
?>
```

The output I get is:

```
string(85) "[{"message":"this is message","number":10},{"message":"this is message","number":10}]"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(15) "this is message"
    ["number"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(15) "this is message"
    ["number"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(15) "this is message"
    ["number"]=>
    int(10)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {
    ["message"]=>
    string(15) "this is message"
    ["number"]=>
    int(10)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$arr       = array(0 => "o1", 1 => "o2");

$json_data = json_encode($arr);

$res       = json_decode($json_data, true);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => o1
    [1] => o2
)
```

Comment: That is array of arrays. what I want is array of objects.

Comment: If your input array contains objects you will get it as objects

Comment: When I call json_decode with only one argument (json_encoded data) What I get is:
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        [1] => Array
    )